# Horizontal Scrolling Ticker Option in Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

The current ticker is awesome, but people who are active in a high-volume (feed and discussion) chatroom have to push dismiss quite often if they don't want the chat window overrun on smaller monitors.

So I thought, what if we had a horizontal scrolling ticker as made famous on various news channels.

Comment: It should be noted that currently the ticker is set to show at most _n_ items (I believe 6), then cycle between screenfuls of items after that.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the current scroller can be saved by having items automatically "expire":

- After five minutes, and
- After they are pushed "out" of the current screenful of items (disabling the current behaviour of cycling between screenfuls of feed items)

However, an horizontal scroller would be graphically cooler I guess :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cycling between screenfuls of feed items"; the oldest message just gets removed when a new one comes in and the maximum threshold is reached (it's eight, btw.)

Comment: @balpha weird, I definitely recall seeing the ticker fade between at least two different sets of items.

Answer (score 1):

This has wound me up no end over the two weeks that I've been using StackOverflow.

In general the SO software is *really* tight, and the chat feature is fantastic. The feed itself is very useful too, but it is *so* invasive as to be a real distraction.

A way to selectively disable the feed showing (I am likely to enable/disable it depending on what I'm doing) or to tuck it away somewhere that's not a pop-up would be very beneficial.